# Teradata SQL - two counts from same column

Tags: sql, count, teradata

I'm new to SQL and Teradata. I tried searching for an answer to this but have been unsuccessful so far.

I created a volatile table with a column that holds a value of <100 (can include negatives). I want to get a total count, a count of all "0"values, a count of all values where 0

I know I could just do a separate statement for each type but for my own knowledge I want to learn the "proper" way. I tried using a similar solution found at this link - [Different value counts on same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297185/different-value-counts-on-same-column) - but that doesn't seem to work since I need to use `>`, `<`, and similar operators.

A layout similar to the table in that thread would be sufficient.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: All I see is `HERE` and I'm hoping it's free money or something

Answer (score 2):

`count` cannot be conditional. It counts all records or if you specify a column, all records where the column is not `null`. use `sum`

```
select count(*) as total,
       sum(case when some_col = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as count_0,
       sum(case when some_col > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as count_above0
from your_table
```

Comment: Of course `COUNT` can be conditional, too :) `COUNT(case when some_col = 0 then 1 end)`

Comment: @dnoeth: Well yes, if you make sure the `else` part is `null`. But isn't that a little hard to get for a beginner? This is how wrong it can be if you don't know that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bea60a/3